# adding an audio file with Javascript to AmCharts

Tags: javascript, audio, amcharts

I created a chart (x-y graph) with Amchart's live editor, and I would like to add a sound file (like a sound player) to the chart. The chart represents the sound file, so the 'player' time location would correspond to a location on the x axis in the chart. I would like these to match up visually, and the clickable field that changes the time in the sound file to extend into the chart (like if a sound file was playing and you wanted to go back to 20s, you would click to the left on the player, aka x=20 on the graph)

Amcharts allows customization with JavaScript, so this is the language I think would be best to integrate a sound file with. If a video could be integrated in the same way, as the visual played in the background, that would be pretty cool too, but not necessary to add.

Comment: Show us what you've done so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your category/x-axis is stored as milliseconds, you can leverage the audio (or video) tag's [`timeupdate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/timeupdate) event and call the `showCursorAt` method in the chart's `chartCursor` object with the new timestamp. You'll need to use a serial chart in order to leverage the `showCursorAt` method, though.

**HTML**

```
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
<audio id="chart-audio" src="/path/to/audio/source"  preload="auto" controls>
</audio>
```

**JavaScript**

```
AmCharts.useUTC = true; //needed for millisecond timestamps
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataProvider": [{
    "y": <value>,
    "x": 0
  }, {
    "y": <value>,
    "x": 1000
  }, {
    "y": <value>,
    "x": 2000
  }, {
    "y": <value>,
    "x": 3000
  }, 
  // .. continue until you have the full length of the song in milliseconds
  ],
  // other config ..
  "categoryField": "x",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "parseDates": true,
    "boldPeriodBeginning": false,
    "dateFormats": [{
      "period": "fff",
      "format": "JJ:NN:SS"
    }, {
      "period": "ss",
      "format": "JJ:NN:SS"
    }, {
      "period": "mm",
      "format": "JJ:NN::SS"
    }, {
      "period": "hh",
      "format": "JJ:NN:SS"
    }, {
      "period": "DD",
      "format": "MMM DD"
    }, {
      "period": "WW",
      "format": "MMM DD"
    }, {
      "period": "MM",
      "format": "MMM"
    }, {
      "period": "YYYY",
      "format": "YYYY"
    }],
    "equalSpacing": true,
    "minPeriod": "ss"
  },
  "chartCursor": {
    "categoryBalloonDateFormat": "JJ:NN:SS",
  }
});

var audio = document.getElementById('chart-audio');

audio.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(e) {
  chart.chartCursor.showCursorAt(new Date(Math.floor(e.target.currentTime * 1000)));
});
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/0498c617344ebba6bbeb3ac26031c6c6)

**Edit**

You're also not necessarily limited to milliseconds. If you have a way to map the media tag's currentTime attribute to the appropriate category in your chart, you can do that as well:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataProvider": [{
    "y": 1,
    "measure": 1
  }, {
    "y": 2,
    "measure": 2
  }, {
    "y": 3,
    "measure": 3
  }, {
    "y": 4,
    "measure": 4
  } ],
  "graphs": [{
    "balloonText": "[[category]]: [[value]]",
    "bullet": "circle",
    "valueField": "y",
  }],
  "categoryField": "measure",
  "chartCursor": { },
});

var audio = document.getElementById("chart-audio");

audio.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(e) {
  var measure;
  var currentTime = e.target.currentTime;
  if (currentTime <= 8) {
    measure = 1;
  }
  else if (currentTime <= 16) {
    measure = 2;
  }
  else if (currentTime <= 24) {
    measure = 3;
  }
  else {
    measure = 4;
  }

  chart.chartCursor.showCursorAt(measure);
});
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/7df1fa2ec0d2eb65296f135d179f3429)

Comment: Wow! This is great!! I am wondering, before I change the values in my data for x into milliseconds (my x axis is not measured in milliseconds, it is grouped by measure numbers), if another value of time could increment the x axis? Would it be harder than its worth to convert to a different increment since milliseconds is easily available?

Comment: The X/category axis doesn't necessarily need to be date-based, so I suppose you could use your measure numbers as your axis increments and try to map the currentTime values from the audio/video tag's timeupdate event (which are in seconds) to those measure numbers and call `showCursorAt` with the corresponding measure number. My music theory knowledge is pretty weak so pardon me if no such mapping exists.  I just used milliseconds since it was the the most direct example I could come up with.

Comment: Here's a quick and dirty example of using a non-date based category to illustrate what I mean: [codepen](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/7df1fa2ec0d2eb65296f135d179f3429). I also updated my answer as well

Comment: Yes that looks great!! Sorry for not explaining. A measure is a marker of musical time. It holds a number of beats; in many cases, there are four beats in a measure. A beat feels like the pulse in a song, the thing you might tap your foot to.. And I am so close to having this synced! I think my problem is that a have multiple lines in my graph, so what I am referencing as my measure may be askew. There are multiple xField; I tried var xField as well as var LocalPositionI etc. This might make more sense here, http://codepen.io/parallelexpressions/pen/RGXNjq.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem is that you're using an XY chart and `showCursorAt` is only supported in a serial chart. You can certainly have multiple lines in a serial chart, you just need a common categoryField (which is effectively your X axis in a serial chart) to tie everything together. This means you can't have different x fields like LocalPositionI/M/HM - it needs to be one field.

Comment: Thanks so much!! It works very well with the serial chart! just one formatting [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40411203/amcharts-width-field-and-parsing-dates)